# switch statement with multiple cases which execute the same code

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I have the following code:

```
<?php

echo check('three');

function check($string) {
  switch($string) {
    case 'one' || 'two' : return 'one or two'; break;
    case 'three' || 'four' : return 'three or four'; break;
  }
}
```

Currently it outputs:

```
one or two
```

But obviously I want the code to return `three or four`.

So what is right method to return the same code for multiple case statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible. the `case` items must be **VALUES**. You have expressions, which means the expressions are evaluated, and the result of that expression is them compared against the value in the `switch()`. That means you've effectively got

```
switch(...) { 
  case TRUE: ...
  case TRUE: ...
}
```

You cannot use multiple values in a case. YOu can, however, use the "fallthrough support":

```
switch(...) {
   case 'one':
   case 'two':
       return 'one or two';
   case 'three':
   case 'four':
       return 'three or four';
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Just write two case statements which execute the same code, e.g.

```
function check($string) {
  switch($string) {
    case 'one':
    case 'two':
        return 'one or two';
    break;

    case 'three':
    case 'four' :
        return 'three or four';
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the break statements though. The execution exits the method on the returns.

Comment: @BCartolo Yes, the return statement would end the function, but just in case you use it somewhere else where you are not in a function I just put the `break;` there.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a mapping dictionary:

```
$oneOrTwo = 'one or two';
$threeOrFour = 'three or four';
$stringsMap = ['one' => $oneOrTwo, 'two' => $oneOrTwo, 'three' => $threeOrFour, 'four' => $threeOrFour];
return $stringsMap[$string]
```

Switch statements can become harder and harder to maintain if more and more values are added.